# How to add a new field to a list view after specific field in this view

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-server, list-view, view

I need to add a new field to a myriad of existing views of a list in a specific position from left (i.e. this new field must be placed after the field 'fulladdress_onlylistdefined', who already resides in all views).

The field i need to add already exists in list columns.

To do so, i suppose the following actions:

-get the web, list, view

-initialize new field

-get all view fields

-iterate through view fields to locate the field after which i need to place my specific field (using field's internal name)

-insert my field, update view and list

-repeat in loop to iterate through views

Script looks like this:

```
    $web = Get-SPWeb http://server
    $list = $web.Lists["Requests"]
    $spView = $Web.GetViewFromUrl("/Lists/Requests/View.aspx")
    $field1 = $list.Fields["MyField"]
    $address = $spview.ViewFields['fulladdress_onlylistdefined']
    $spview.ViewFields.Add($field1)
    $spview.ViewFields.MoveFieldTo($address,'4')
    $spview.Update()
```

But i got two problems:

1. When trying to access specific element from ViewFields fields collection i got null instead:

   ```
   $address = $spview.ViewFields['fulladdress_onlylistdefined']  
   $address variable is blank
   ```
2. `$spview.ViewFields.MoveFieldTo` method won't accept a variable $address as a parameter

My doubt was i should iterate through array, not through collection, but i'm unable to create an array:

```
    $array = @(([array]::CreateInstance([string], 0)))
    $coll=$spview.ViewFields.ToStringCollection()
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $coll.Count; $i++)
        {
      $array=+$coll[$i]
        }

    Cannot convert value "Edit" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in         a correct format."
```

So the final questions are:

- How to access specific field in `$spview.ViewFields` fields collection? Especially by its name.
- How to work with `$spview.ViewFields.MoveFieldTo` method to place a field after specific field in a view?
- What is the best way to achieve my task?

Thanks!

PS To prevent some solutions, this one does not suit me:

```
    $spview.ViewFields.DeleteAll();

    $spview.ViewFields.Add($field1)
    $spview.ViewFields.Add($field2)
    $spview.ViewFields.Add($field3)
    etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've finished with creating console application.

I'm not great in C# so it is a bit bulky but this solution works.

If there is any mistakes, i will be glad to hear about it.

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\temp\views.csv"));
            List<string> listA = new List<string>();
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(';');
            listA.Add(values[0]);
        }
        var data = listA.ToArray();
        SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite("http://server");
        using (SPWeb oWebsite = oSiteCollection.RootWeb)
        {
            SPList oList = oWebsite.Lists["Requests"];
            foreach (string i in data)
            {
                SPView oView = oWebsite.GetViewFromUrl(i.Substring(19));
                SPViewFieldCollection collViewFields = oView.ViewFields;
                System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection collStrings = oView.ViewFields.ToStringCollection();
                var z = collStrings.IndexOf("fulladdress_onlylistdefined");
                collViewFields.Add("RequestVoltageTotal");
                oView.Update();
                Console.WriteLine("Field added: RequestVoltageTotal");
                collViewFields.MoveFieldTo("RequestVoltageTotal", z + 1);
                oView.Update();
            }
```